# how to use php and volt parameter together?

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I am using Volt and PHP in **phalcon volt** partial

I want to iterate a **loop** and in the loop I have php code that accept a parameter

this is my code

```
{% for header in headers %}
<th>
    <?=gettext( {{header}} );?>
</th>
{% endfor %}
```

here `header`  is a **parameter** that is used in php code

but I get this error

[image]

what is the **right** way to **rewrite** this code

Answer (score 1):

You can configure some services in a better way to help you solve this issue.

If you define your view service like:

```
    $di->set('view', function () {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setDI($this);
        $view->setViewsDir(__DIR__ . '/views/');

        $view->registerEngines([
            '.volt'  => 'voltShared'
        ]);

        return $view;
    });
```

You can define your voltShared service improving the volt compiler with custom functions in this way:

```
$di->setShared('voltShared', function ($view) use ($di) {
    $config = $this->getConfig();

    $volt = new VoltEngine($view, $this);
    $volt->setOptions([
        'autoescape'        => false,
        'compileAlways'     => true,
        'stat'              => true,
        'compiledSeparator' => '_',
        'compiledPath'      => $config->application->cacheDir.'volt/',
    ]);

    // We add some custom functions
    $compiler = $volt->getCompiler();
    $compiler->addFunction('gettext', function ($resolvedArgs) {
        return 'gettext('.$resolvedArgs.')';
    })

    return $volt;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to use a raw PHP function here, so correct me if I'm wrong. Unfortunately I forget the exact reason this is (I learned a long time), but you have to manually register PHP functions in the Volt Engine in order to use them. This can be done using the `addFunction` method of the Engine will allow you to add them. I thought it had been resolved that this wasn't needed anymore, but it was reported in https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/12841.

Anyways, using `addFunction`: I've used the below to get around this:

```
foreach (get_defined_functions()['Internal'] as $functionName) {
    $voltEngine->addFunction($functionName, $functionName);
}
```

You have to put this in the code that initializes the volt engine.

Comment: yes , i use raw php function

Answer (score -1):

Reading [documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/volt#overview) shows that echo command is using `{{ }}` instead of normal PHP tag `<?= ?>`:

```php
{% for header in headers %}
<th>
    {{ gettext(header) }}
</th>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i tested this BUT i have error :"Macro 'gettext' does not exist"

Comment: So ensure that macro exists